# window.location.href returns "(canceled)" and returns to previous page

Tags: javascript, c#, model-view-controller, razor

I have a curious issue.  I am working on an Edit page which allows me to edit all aspects of a custom Report object.  A Report sends a Message to an end user to notify them of the status of the Report after it runs.  When I click the "Edit Message" button on the Edit Report page, the onclick function calls the EditMessage javascript, which sets window.location.href to the following:

```
'@Url.Action("EditMessage", "Reports")?msgId=' + listId
```

I've also tried adding the / before the ?:

```
'@Url.Action("EditMessage", "Reports")/?msgId=' + listId
```

...neither works.

The EditMessage Action fires successfully, and passes the View back to the controller.

Once the page is completely built, the browser's Developer Tools shows me this:

[image]

...then it returns to the Reports/Index page.  Because it's showing a Redirect (302) to Reports/Edit/17, I would expect it to return to the Edit page, instead.

The really strange part is that if I grab the Request URL:

[image]

...and enter it in the address bar, it loads the page just fine.

Does anyone have any thoughts on this?  It's been bugging me for a few hours, now, and google isn't helping at all.

Comment: Try like this `Url.Action("EditMessage", "Reports", new { msgId = listId} )`

Comment: @SelimYıldız: No change.  Still does the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Are you calling your function using **onsubmit** ?

**cancelled** mean the redirection couldn't finish the redirection process cause something terminated it

**onsubmit** by example will refresh the current page when the function is done (this also explain why people make it work using timeout)

So calling it in another way could fix your problem, again taking the **onsubmit** example, you would replace it using a **button** and calling **onclick**